# Indexing different documents to same object in RavenDb

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

I am indexing 2 different documents as below.

```
public class User
{
    public UserId UserId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class UserGroup
{
    public UserGroupId UserGroupId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

//this is for indexing result
public class SecurityObject
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public virtual SecurityObjectType ObjectType { get; set; }
}
```

My query is as below. As you can see in `Index` configuration that I mapped `Name` property to `DisplayName` but `DisplayName` property is `null` when the returning document is `UserGroup`. When I review the fetched documents `Name` property is not mapped to `DisplayName` property and real value still stays on `Name` property. How can I correctly transform that `Name` property to `DisplayName` property on `UserGroup`?

```
_session.Query<SecurityObject, SecurityObjectIndex>()
    .Where(s => s.DisplayName.StartsWith(searchTerm))
    .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<SecurityObject>();
```

And here is my indexing configuration:

```
public class SecurityObjectIndex
    : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<SecurityObject>
{
    public override string IndexName
    {
        get
        {
            return "UserAndUserGroup/SecurityObjectIndex";
        }
    }

    public SecurityObjectIndex()
    {
        AddMap<User>(users => from u in users
                              select new
                              {
                                  DisplayName = u.DisplayName,
                                  ObjectType = SecurityObjectType.Users
                              });

        AddMap<UserGroup>(userGroups => from u in userGroups
                                        select new 
                                      { 
                                          DisplayName = u.Name,
                                          ObjectType = SecurityObjectType.Groups
                                      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to project from index fields, those fields must be *stored* with the index.  Add the following to your index definition:

```
Store(x=> x.DisplayName, FieldStorage.Yes);
Store(x=> x.ObjectType, FieldStorage.Yes);
```

Alternatively, you can use this shortcut method:

```
StoreAllFields(FieldStorage.Yes);
```

But personally I prefer to mark each one separately.